# Dúvida sobre Framework

Tags: framework, sass, bootstrap

Buenas Devs!

Sou novo na área e estou enfrentando uma dúvida que literalmente vem tirando meu sono...
Qual é o melhor (facilidade x desempenho) framework a ser utilizado atualmente?

W3.CSS
SCSS
SASS
Bootstrap

Andei lendo algumas coisas na internet que só aumentaram minhas dúvidas, quando descobri esse site Stackoverflow, vi a oportunidade de ter minha dúvida retirada por profissionais da área.

Muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: depende do que vc esta procurando o que vc quer atingir?

Answer (score 1):

Apenas o W3.CSS e o Bootstrap são realmente frameworks, SASS e SCSS são formas de escrever código de estilo, igual ao CSS. Mas vamos lá:

Tudo isso é uma questão de gosto/mercado, eu como desenvolvedor front-end, vou acabar esbarrando e tendo que aprender as vezes os dois, dependendo da necessidade da empresa onde trabalho. Pra começar, eu recomendo você estudar o Bootstrap ou o Foundation, pois ambos são bem robustos e "velhos" no mercado. Ou seja, você vai conseguir sanar sua dúvida bem rapidamente.

Mas lembre-se, para usar esses frameworks você precisa conhecer a linguagem que ele utiliza, no caso do Bootstrap/Foundation/W3.CSS é baseado em CSS e um pouco de HTML e Javascript.

Espero que tenha esclarecido suas dúvidas ;)

Comment: SASS e SCSS são as sintaxes da linguagem pré-processada SASS, elas são convertidas em CSS.